# How to log MySql queries fired in JasperReports Server?

Tags: logging, jasper-reports, jasperserver

i have seen many results with same query in Google some i understood/tries and some not working and some suggests a solution which start from the middle. like [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802433/how-do-i-get-jasperserver-log-queries-it-performs) and tried [this one](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/526007/logging-sql-query-executed) made change in *log4j.properties* not working and [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/logging-sql-queries-generated-domain-reports) I have tried making those changes and saw catelina.out for debug statements i didn't get anything.

Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Product Version: 6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of jasper report queries logging i used `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'` to log mysql queries fired which is given by jasper report. we should run that command in mysql terminal. and then in /var/lib/mysql(mine ubuntu 14) you will see *.log* file where you can check for queries fired